# Is it possible to write a single dbt test which applies to all tables in the whole project?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-science, dbt, anomaly-detection

To ensure that new data is constantly arriving in Snowflake without interruption, I want to add some tests to my dbt project. I want to use [freshness_anomalies test in Elementary](https://docs.elementary-data.com/guides/add-elementary-tests), which is a package supporting dbt.

I can't figure out a way to only set up this test once so that the test is done on all tables. What I can do so far is something like this:
[excerpt from sources.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPpYX.png)

But this way, I have to add these lines for the test for each and every table I am creating in dbt, and I have many...

Is it possible to write the test only once? Btw, every single table has the column "META_LOAD_DATETIME", so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include the text of the code in your answer, instead of a screenshot. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately for you, `tests` are Properties, not Configs, so they can only be defined in "Property" files (i.e., schema.yml files). [Source](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/configs-and-properties#which-properties-are-not-also-configs). This means you need to write out the test property on every model/seed/source/etc. that you want it to run on.

`.yml` files are easy to generate programmatically, so if you wanted to do this hundreds or thousands of times, I would write a script for that. You could also use something like [`dbt_pre_commit`](https://docs.getdbt.com/blog/enforcing-rules-pre-commit-dbt) to enforce the presence of this test for new models.

Comment: yes but if you have lets say 300 worth of models being able to say run no null test on everything and not having to write out every model in a config file would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

There's a way actually - but it's more of a workaround. **This answer is to help people who want to write tests consisting of all models, not specific to this question.**

*When would you want a test that applies to all models?*  For eg: You want to test if the schema.yml of the project contains the right columns as present in the dbt pipeline models.

You can write a generic test which applies to all models. **For OP's case, he will have to tweak the test maybe by looking at the source code of the `freshness_anomalies` test**

```
{% test all_columns_defined_in_schema_present_in_models(model) %}
    {% if execute %}
        {% set models = [] %}
        -- Get the models from the DAG
        {% for node in graph.nodes.values() | selectattr("resource_type", "equalto", "model") %}
                {% do models.append(node) %}
        {% endfor %}

        -- Iterate on each model
        {% for model in models %}
  
            -- This has to be tweaked
            SELECT
            NULL AS placeholder
            FROM {{ model.database ~ "." ~ model.schema ~ "." ~ model.name }}
            WHERE 1=0
            {% for column_name in model.columns %}
                AND {{ column_name }} IS NULL
            {% endfor %}
            {% if not loop.last %}UNION ALL{% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endtest %}
```

The source for this comes from the discussion going on here - https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/1570#issuecomment-1500395582